# how to make my two player checkers application ,a one player checkers application

Tags: android

I have developed my first android application i.e. CHECKERS ,which is working perfectly for two players, now some users  of my app wants me to add a single player mode as well.
Can you guys plz help me how can I fulfill this demand,How to code for this.Your help will be highly respected.
I used canvas drawing in my app and my class extends SurfaceView implements runnable.

Thanks!

Comment: Look up some strategies for how to play checkers, then write those into rules that make it challenging but not impossible to play.

Comment: If you need help with your code, post it. If you have a specific problem, post it. But don´t expect us to write your code.

Comment: Just copy your two player code, but make the computer do the second player's moves.

Answer (score 2):

I am willing to help you with ideas:

I assume you already have a project, which works with two players. If you want to achieve 1-player mode without too much pain, you should follow the ideas described below:

1. Create a ComputerPlayer class, inherit it from your Player class.
2. Override methods, such as move to occur automatically (at first, start with random moves, don't get delved deep into the AI logic just yet, because first you want to support automatic moves, and then you will want to focus on AI strategies)
3. Where you send/receive the moves support sending/receiving moves from ComputerPlayer as well (you will not really send a message to the network, but your current project probably uses terminology as "send", "receive")
4. Test, test and test.
5. When everything is well, choose an AI strategy, implement it and you are done with the upgrade.